# Email template not using themed version

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3 and the built in email features as described in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Email.html).  I have the html version of the template located in app/views/elements/email/html/reservation.ctp and its working as expected.

```
$this->Email->template = 'reservation'; // no '.ctp'
```

I also have a theme setup and most of the themed files are correctly overriding the default files.  My problem is the themed email template is not being used when called from the themed site, its still using the email template file in the default path.

The default is at: app/views/elements/email/html/reservation.ctp

The theme is at: app/views/themed/myTheme/elements/email/html/reservation.ctp

Should the email template assignment automatically work with themes without the need for hard coding a path or is there another solution?  Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Are you sending the email from within a controller? If so, is the `view` class set to `Theme`? The email-component will use the same view-class as the controller and *should* also use the same theme: see the source [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/controller/components/email.php#L455). On a side-note: is the project you're working on a *new* project? CakePHP 1.3 is really becoming old and a **lot** of improvements have been made in CakePHP 2.x (also on themes)

Comment: Yes, view is set to theme in AppController. I see the issue.  I set the theme based on the url in the AppController beforeRender   function.  Sending the email never calls the beforeRender function therefore the theme is never set.  Created a new function to set the theme and then I call the function in the beforeRender or as needed. Thanks for your comment, helped me clarify the issue.

Comment: Want me to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

in cakephp when you want to create email template. Lets suppose we want to create an Html email. and email config is configured.

Views[File Structure]:

1) your content email with variables should be located in View/Emails/html [reservation.ctp]
2) your template should be located in View/Layouts/Emails/html [default.ctp OR any new template you have made]

controllers:

**Note:** some people think when you write an action(in controller) you have to write a view for it. In this case (for sending email) is completely wrong. only if you want to show the result which email sent successfully or not then is fine.

lets say ReserveController ;) and sendReservationEmail

```
function sendReservationEmail( $to, $from,$subject ,$template, $variables=array()){

        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->config('smtp')
            ->viewVars($variables) 
            ->emailFormat('html')
            ->template($template['page'], $template['layout'])  //'reservation', 'default'
            ->from($from)                                      //'me@example.com' => 'My Site'    
            ->to($to)                                          //'you@example.com'
            ->subject($subject) //'Resevation'
            ->send();       
    }
```

Views (View/Emails/html/reservation.ctp):

```
Dear $this->viewVars['name'];

Welcome to our restaurant .....
```